# How to calculate concentrations and what is the concept of 'mole'?

Tags: homework, solutions, numerical-analysis

Say I have a $50~\mathrm{ml}$ solution of a liquid mixture which is $30~\%$ concentrated. Now if I take $20~\mathrm{ml}$ of that liquid out from that mix, what would be the resulting concentration of both the liquid remaining and the liquid extracted? Will the concentration of both still be $30~\%$?

Comment: This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Comment: What do **you** think? Please provide your thoughts so we can guide you better.

Comment: According to me the concentration should remain the same since it is dependent on moles and hence even if we take out 20ml from a concentrated solution the moles should not be affected. However my doubt lies in the fact that does this stand true in all terms of concentration , eg in cases of molarity or maybe volume by volume concentrations etc

Comment: @SushmitaNayak yes, if it is a solution all portions will have the same concentration.  If it is merely a "mixture", like orange juice, then not necessarily.

Comment: Please guide me by explaining the main concept and not by random values used in the question

Comment: @SushmitaNayak the main concept is that all samples, portions, subdivisions, etc. of  a solution have the same concentration.

Comment: So that means even it is a 1M solution or a 20% solution(volume by volume) all of them technically on changing the volume do not get affected by the concentration ?

Comment: You have to assume that the solvated molecules are *uniformly distributed* in the liquid for all subdivisions of the liquid to have same concentration. If you have a glass of lemonade, and pour half of it into another glass, you will have two glasses of lemonade of the same strength. See the point?

Answer (score 1):

Concentration of a liquid can be given by the formula **C=N/V**, where V is the volume of the solution and N is the number of moles present in it.

To help you understand exactly what a 'mole' is, think of it like this: when you ad a certain amount of powder to water, say sugar or a fruit drink, how many spoons/ grams of powder you add is the number of moles. (1 mole is actually 6.02214129 * 10^23 particles of the substance)

The concentration can be determined by how much water you add to the drink: If you add more water, the solution is said to be **diluted**, since the ratio of solute:solvent is lower. So in a drink with 30% concentration, the ratio would be 3:7, 3 moles of powder for 7 moles of water. The concentration can ONLY BE CHANGED if the amount of water changes. The ratio remains same throughout, so concentration would be 30% if you take 20ml, 10ml, or any measurement of volume.

Hope this train of thought helped your mind to get the reasoning :)